# b4a Insert Timer in a code

Tags: vb4android

I am french so sorry for my english i do my best...

I try to call a sub named timer1_tick and i want it to stop my sub "b_reponse1_click". The problem is that my sub dont wait until the end of the timer...

Code:

```
Sub Process_Globals
  Dim Timer1 As Timer
  ....
  End Sub

Sub Activity_Create(FirstTime As Boolean)
 Timer1.Initialize("Timer1", 1000) ' 1000 = 1 second
 Timer1.Enabled = True
 ...
 End Sub

Sub b_reponse1_Click
p= p + 1
If b_reponse1.Text = r5 Then
    score = score + 1
    b_reponse1.Color=Colors.Green
    CallSub("",timer1_tick)      ' Here i call sub timer1_tick 
    b_reponse1.Color=Colors.Gray
    Else
    b_reponse1.Color=Colors.Red
    b_reponse1.Color=Colors.Gray
End If

If nbqpassee = 10 Then
    Activity.RemoveAllViews
    Activity.LoadLayout("lay_main")
    Else
        CallSub("",loadq)
End If
End Sub
```

Timer1 countdown but my sub b_reponse1_Click continue execution without waiting the end of timer

Timer :

Code:

```
Sub timer1_tick
 t = t + 1
 Log(t)
End Sub
```

I have try this but didn't solve my problem :

Code:

```
 Sub timer1_tick
 t = t + 1
 Log(t)
 timer1.Enabled = False
 End Sub
```

Do you know how can i do to stop my sub b_reponse1_click about to 1 second ?

Thanks by advance for answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

timer1_tick is a regular sub like any other sub. It will not cause the code execution to wait.

Search the forum for CallSubPlus. You can break your current sub to two subs and then call the second sub with CallSubPlus which will run after the specified time.